# Parsing error: babel.loadPartialConfigSync is not a function

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, app-config, babel-loader

Getting this error in React js. Tried to update the babel and change the babel.config file but didn't solved.

I am trying to run my react js application using npm start and getting this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I pull a repo and try to run using npm install and npm start then I got this error. 
Which code should I share I can understand as I got this problem in running the code.

I also go through https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11853 
but it didn't work for me.